# Set specific background color of image to transparent using JS

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following code to modify the transparency on an image. What I would like to do however is only modify the background color of the image and set its alpha channel to 0 instead of the entire image.

Following code sets the alpha transparency to 0 for the entire image:

```
var ctx = this.data.getContext("2d");
var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, this.data.width, this.data.height);
ctx.putImageData(this.adjustImage(imgData), 0, 0);

adjustImage: function(iArray) {
    var imageData = iArray.data;
    for (var i = 0; i < imageData.length; i+= 4) {
        imageData[i+3] = 0;
    }

    return iArray;            
}
```

I'm after some help modifying only one color `rgb(255,0,255)` in the image to transparent.

Comment: You can get the color at a particular pixel, like so
`var imgd = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
        var data = imgd.data;
        var out = $('#result');
        var hexString = RGBtoHex(data[0],data[1],data[2]);`

and then you can check if the color matches the required value and set alpha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't really tested this, but this should work

```
var ctx = this.data.getContext("2d");
var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, this.data.width, this.data.height);
ctx.putImageData(this.adjustImage(imgData), 0, 0);

adjustImage: function(iArray) {
    var imageData = iArray.data;
    for (var i = 0; i < imageData.length; i+= 4) {
        if(imageData[i] === 255 && imageData[i+1] === 0 && imageData[i+2] === 255){
            imageData[i+3] = 0;
        }
    }

    return iArray;            
}
```