# overlay image with single rgb transparent color in html5/css

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

I would like to read a picture (gif color image) with a fixed background rgb color, say (0,0,0), into my html5 program, and overlay it on another image, with only that background color transparent. Note this background is not a fixed shape -- it is, for instance, the sky with a foreground bird flying across it. I just want to see the bird.
I tried the following,

```
<div style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 39px; left: 72pix; background-color: #ffffff; opacity: 0.5">

<img alt="overlay image" src="overlay.gif" WIDTH=32 HEIGHT=32></div></div>
```

but this makes the whole overlay 0.5 transparent.
I tried inserting this,

```
<div style="background: rgba(0,0,0,0.0)"></div>
```

but this doesn't change the image rgb values, only sets the actual background around the image.

Comment: I would use photo editing software to create transparency. Try something like photoshop or paint.net.

Comment: Thanks. Although I didn't say, it's not a single image I want to overlay; I read an avi movie file, and each frame is my image that I want transparency of the background. I don't think movie formats have a transparency value like png.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to do this using CSS/HTML only.  It will require SVG or JavaScript.  Answer to similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339496/set-specific-background-color-of-image-to-transparent-using-js).

Comment: Thanks. You have saved me more futile searching in CSS/HTML documents. I was hoping it could be done at a higher level than javaScript, but it is no problem to do it there -- and thank you for the javaScript link.