# Change transparent to color in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, colors, transparent

I'm having trouble finding a solution to change the transparency of an image to a color rgb. Is this possible?

Comment: Use any image manipulation program

Answer (score 0):

To change the "transparency" of an element you need to use the `opacity` attribute. If the image is transparent, its opacity is set to 0. This means you need to change the opacity to "1" then you can change the color.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GVzFr/)

HTML

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var div = document.getElementById('test');
div.style.opacity = '1';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(imageData[i] === 255 && imageData[i+1] === 0 && imageData[i+2] === 255) {
        imageData[i+3] = 0;
    }
```

(see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11340901/1729094) answer)