# How to use tesseract.js to recognize a date and numbers on a lotto ticket?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ocr, image-recognition

My app attempts to recognize the draw date and played numbers on a lottery ticket. However, I'm not able to detect the date nor the numbers because of the images on the background of the ticket. How do I modify my code to be able to achieve my goal?

Initially I tried to find an API that would accept the bar code of the lottery ticket and return if the ticket is a winning ticket or not. After extensive research on the web I came to realize that such an approach is not possible so now I'm attempting to use character recognition methods to detect the numbers and draw date. With this information I will then cross reference it against the winning numbers and draw date.
The upside here is that the desired characters is in black and everything else have a different color.
I tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339496/set-specific-background-color-of-image-to-transparent-using-js/) logic but I struggled to manipulate the code to suite my purpose.

[image: image of a lottery ticket]

The desired code would output the "First Draw:" date and the 6 numbers played (to the right of A06:).

What I actually got is the following:

“no“
LO 0
“Wm“{
3153:» -.: , .4,
LDTTU PLUS,.;: 7N9"???
ms: 10 20 24 25 32 3.7
Total :R5 ‘00 . 7‘
hc? ‘E:
IWHW 753:"
15/0/19 FE:4¢;1-
071094555258an94

```js
//function I use to run OCR
function runOCR(url) {
  Tesseract.recognize(url)
    .then(function(result) {
      console.log(result.text);
    }).progress(function(result) {
      console.log('Status: ' + result['status']);
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance for an effective solution.
I just need someone to assist me in pixel out the red and white background so that the foreground becomes easily recognizable. I'm interested in two lines here: The draw date, which read **First Draw: Saterday 20/07/19** and **A06: 10 20 24 25 32 37**

Comment: I'm a bit sorry that I can't help you as such a question is rarely answered :/ You said tough: ` I just need someone to assist me in pixel out the red and white background so that the foreground becomes easily recognizable.`. If you're having trouble telling fore and background apart you should take a look a [thresholding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing)). And here is a good [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRM5Js3VLCk) about all sorts of image processing which includes working code for thresholding.

Comment: What I need is a function that would iterate over every pixel in a given image and compare it against a black color value. If the pixel is equal or greater, in color, than the specified black pixel value than the pixel remain it's color otherwise change it to a white pixel. My problem is I don't know how to do this comparison or even do a search for the solution. You know now what I need and I would appreciate it if you could write the code for me. Thanks.

Comment: That's exactly what I've sent you. I might take a look at it but please try it your self.

Comment: Okay. I'm coding it now. Thank you so long :)

Comment: How do I change the if condition to test for a black pixel threshold (let say the lightest black pixel in the image): for(var i = 0; i+3 < imageData.data.length; i+=4) { r = imageData.data[i]; g = imageData.data[i+1]; b = imageData.data[i+2]; a = imageData.data[i+3];;if((r > 0 || g > 0 || b > 0) && a > 0) { imageData.data[i+3] = 0;}}. //Sorry for the compacted code.

Comment: I figured it out. I just adjusted the rgb values with +10 again and again until I got the desired outcome. I'm on r > 150 || g > 150 || b >150 now and so far the background is totally white and foreground completely black. I'm going to still tweak the values though until it's picture perfect. I would just like to say thank you very much.

Comment: Haha I'm glad I could help. Sometimes you just need to know that to goole for :D Have fun coding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sooo... Well I gave it a shot.

I first convert the image to a grayscale image and then check if the value is above or below the threshold. Just upload the image and move the slider to change the threshold value.

(And you probably need to open it in full page lol)

Have a good one :)

```js
const fileReader      = document.getElementById('fileReader');
const sliderThreshold = document.getElementById('sliderThreshold');
const inputCanvas     = document.getElementById('inputCanvas');
const outputCanvas    = document.getElementById('outputCanvas');
const inputCtx        = inputCanvas.getContext('2d');
const outputCtx       = outputCanvas.getContext('2d');


sliderThreshold.addEventListener('input', e => displayResult(e.target.value));


fileReader.addEventListener('change', inputEvent => {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('load', readerEvent => {
    let img = new Image();
    img.addEventListener('load', () => {
      inputCanvas.width  = img.width;
      inputCanvas.height = img.height;
      inputCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

      displayResult(50);
    });
    img.src = readerEvent.target.result;
  });
  reader.readAsDataURL(inputEvent.target.files[0]);
});



function displayResult(threshold) {
  let imageData = inputCtx.getImageData(0,0, inputCanvas.width, inputCanvas.height);
  let data = imageData.data;

  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    // Convert RGB values to grayscale (you can look that up)
    let grayscale = data[i] * 0.3 + data[i + 1] * 0.59 + data[i + 2] * 0.11;

    // Check if the value is obove or below the threshold value and return white or black
    let finalColor = grayscale < threshold ? 0 : 255;

    // Asign the color
    data[i]     = finalColor;
    data[i + 1] = finalColor;
    data[i + 2] = finalColor;
  }

  // Put the data into another canvas so we 
  outputCanvas.width = imageData.width;
  outputCanvas.height = imageData.height;
  outputCtx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .canvasContainer {
      overflow-y: scroll;
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" id="fileReader">
  Threshold<input type="range" min="0" max="255" id="sliderThreshold">


  <div class="canvasContainer">
    <canvas id="outputCanvas"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="canvasContainer">
    <canvas id="inputCanvas"></canvas>
  </div>



  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, I was wondering if I can ask you something about traineddata? (I cannot ask questions anymore.)

Comment: Sure you can :) It's not my expertise though. (And why can't you ask questions anymore?)

Comment: You're awesome! I use tesseract cdn in website and now I want to use my own traineddata language but the recognize function doesn't seem to use it. I create a settings variable to set the path to where eng.traineddata.gz is and pass the var as the second parameter of the recognize method. I get back the same result as I do when I only pass the image. I tested tesseract in windows and replaced the traineddata file with my own and got what I want. What should I do to have tesseract use my traineddata language? (I think I changed the question topic now I'm banned from asking questions for 6mnts)

Comment: Maybe Tesseract add my traineddata to theirs so what I only want is for it to use only my language. The 7 in the image gets recognized with 1 and sometimes not at all. I'm trying to get a text (string) representation of the image (lotto ticket) so I'm using OCR on an image, taken with the user's camera phone. If you have a simpler solution that would be great too.

Comment: I'm really sorry. I can't help you with that as my job is full-stack-web-app developer and I have no expertise in that field at all. Sorry.

Comment: I understand. Did you understand the problem at least? It is a web-app.